# How to find corners from coordinate points

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

i am working with coordinate points i got from the edges of images any of which might have 3 to 4 corners (edges are not smooth so i need to find the largest obvious corner) how do i go about this and find all of the corners for any coordinate points given ( can i plot a graph with the points and use the polygon

[image: The graph plotted with the points]

this particular one has four corners I will like to detect and then split into it's respective 4 sides

Comment: You must first define what is the criteria for being a _corner_. Is it a corner if it's, say, narrower than 170 degrees? Otherwise one could also say that this shape is a triangle, and the top right part is just jaggy.

Comment: You could compute the curvature at every point (after smoothing). Then find the 4 highest curvature points. See Wikipedia for curvature.

Comment: Use the ```approxPolyDP()```. See [Contour Features](https://docs.opencv.org/4.7.0/dd/d49/tutorial_py_contour_features.html).

Comment: @fmw42 i tried smoothing it using cubichermitspline method, but i had to clean the data for it to work like removing recurring x coordinate values and its equivalent y coordinate, the smoothing did not work out because i lost most of the important coordinates. what else can i do to compute the curvature

Comment: What do you mean by "lost"?  Was the data removed completely or was it just moved?  Rather than a spline to connect your data, try just linear interpolation between successive points.

Comment: @fmw42 the data was completely removed, I will try the linear interpolation, thanks for your help